# Can PySpark work without Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed PySpark standalone/locally (on Windows) using

```
pip install pyspark
```

I was a bit surprised I can already run `pyspark` in command line or use it in Jupyter Notebooks and that it does not need a proper Spark installation (e.g. I did not have to do most of the steps in this tutorial https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c ).

Most of the tutorials that I run into say one needs to "install Spark before installing PySpark". That would agree with my view of PySpark being basically a wrapper over Spark. But maybe I am wrong here - can someone explain:

- what is the exact connection between these two technologies?
- why is installing PySpark enough to make it run? Does it actually install Spark under the hood? If yes, where?
- if you install only PySpark, is there something you miss (e.g. I cannot find the `sbin` folder which contains e.g. script to start history server)

Comment: The `pyspark` package is a Spark installation, although you may need to install Java separately.

Comment: How can I run pyspark without Java? I want to use dataframe like SQL. I must use Pandas instead, am I right?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[As of v2.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18267?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK%20AND%20component%20%3D%20PySpark%20AND%20text%20~%20%22pip%22), executing `pip install pyspark` will install Spark.

If you're going to use Pyspark it's clearly the simplest way to get started.

On my system Spark is installed inside my virtual environment (miniconda) at `lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars`

Comment: Thanks Kirk. Are the jars basically "whole of Spark"? Or is there something else one misses when installing pyspark (e.g. the stuff in sbin folder)?

Comment: No, this is Spark and you can run the scala shell (`spark-shell`) and submit jars for execution (`spark-submit`). Of course, it is a single node in a stand-alone configuration - you'll need to configure a cluster if you want to scale.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst That doesn't answer the question in @Ferrard's comment. The Spark directory inside a miniconda environment is missing the `sbin` subdirectory.

Comment: Does `conda install pypark` install spark as well, or should i use `pip`?

Comment: @dashnick Yes, `conda` can also install it. But note that PySpark at Conda is not necessarily synced with PySpark release cycle because it is maintained by the community separately.

Answer (score 8):

PySpark installed by pip is a subfolder of full Spark. you can find most of PySpark python file in `spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark`. so if you'd like to use java or scala interface, and deploy distribute system with hadoop, you must download full Spark from [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and install it.

Answer (score 4):

PySpark has a Spark installation installed. If installed through pip3, you can find it with `pip3 show pyspark`.  Ex. for me it is at `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark`.

This is a [standalone configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) so it can't be used for managing clusters like a full Spark installation.