# What is the difference between PySpark and Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am asking a question very similar to [this SO question on pyspark and spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51728177/1930402)
This answer explains that the pyspark installation does have spark in it. What happens when I do this through Anaconda ? And, is there any other way to run this in PyCharm ? Because, my jupyter notebooks run well with this.

I am very confused about Spark and Pyspark starting right from the installation.

I understand that PySpark is a wrapper to write scalable spark scripts using python. All I did was through anaconda, I installed it.

`conda install pyspark`. I could import it in the script.

But, while I try to run scripts through PyCharm, these warnings come up and the code just stays as is, not stopped though.

`Missing Python executable 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.9', defaulting to 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\bin\..' for SPARK_HOME environment variable. Please install Python or specify the correct Python executable in PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON or PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable to detect SPARK_HOME safely.`

It clearly tells that these environment variables need to be set

There are a lot of resources on installing Spark and I went through many and followed [this](https://github.com/kvfrans/cs224-solutions/tree/master/a1):

I just don't understand the link between all of this. This may be a very trivial question, but I am just feeling so helpless.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

(Over)simplify explanation: **Spark** is a [data processing framework](http://spark.apache.org/). The Spark core is implemented by [Scala](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/index.html) and [Java](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html), but it also provides different **wrappers** including [Python (PySpark)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html), [R (SparkR)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html), and [SQL (Spark SQL)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html).

You can install Spark separately (which would include **all** of the wrappers), or install Python version only by using `pip` or `conda`.